# How to pass sensitive value to file_line without appearing in log

Tags: puppet

I have a Puppet manifest that takes a password from a Hiera config (stored with hiera-eyaml), and inserts it into a config file on my target, but don't see how to do this without the plaintext password appearing in the logs with the catalog. I have a config file  `/etc/example.conf` where the password wants inserting. I've tried:

```
class config::add_password (
  Sensitive $pwd,
) {
  file_line { 'password':
    ensure => present,
    path   => '/etc/example.conf',
    match  => '^Password=',
    line   => "Password=${pwd}",
  }
}
```

If I do this, then the password is not shown in my logs, as I'd want:

```
{"type":"File_line","title":"password","tags":["file_line","class","add_password","config","add_password"],"file":"config/manifests/add_password.pp","line":39,"exported":false,"parameters":{"ensure":"present","path":"/etc/example.conf","match":"^Password=","line":"Password=Sensitive [value redacted]"}},
```

but then `/etc/example.conf` literally contains `Password=Sensitive [value readacted]`.

If instead I have, `line => "Password=${pwd.unwrap}"`, my config file ends up correct, but the log contains the plaintext password. How do you properly use sensitive values so that the password **is not** in the catalog log, but **is** inserted into the file?

Answer (score 1):

Currently the only path forward for returning a `Secret[String]` while still redacting in the Puppet logger (because it would not be unwrapped) would be to render the resulting `String` as a return from an `epp` function. You could then use `inline_epp` to use the `file_line` resource instead of converting to managing the file with a `.epp` file.

```
class config::add_password (
  Sensitive[String] $pwd,
) {
  file_line { 'password':
    ensure => present,
    path   => '/etc/example.conf',
    match  => '^Password=',
    line   => inline_epp("Password=<%= password %>", {'password' => $pwd })
  }
}
```

Note that this is only possible in [Puppet >= 6.20](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/6/securing-sensitive-data.html#securing_sensitive_data-epp-templates), and that [inline_epp](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/7/lang_template_epp.html#epp_use-evaluating-epp-template-strings) is only meant to be used in rare workaround cases like this, and should not be considered a common design pattern.

Comment: Thanks! One slight complication: I'm actually using Bolt (3.9.0), and making use of this with `apply` – I'm not sure what version of Puppet that corresponds to. Should I be able to use Embedded Puppet here? My first attempt didn't succeed, but I may have made another mistake.

Comment: @MikeLynch It would be the version of Puppet installed on your clients during the SSH connection.

Comment: I got stuck on this at the time, but I finally figured this out! Should that instead be `inline_epp('Password=<%= $password %>', {'password' => $pwd})` or `inline_epp("Password=<%= \$password %>", {'password' => $pwd})` ?